# Building a large modular solution with shared components

Tags: .net, tfs, projects-and-solutions

## The Background

I am creating a tool that loads assemblies at runtime to perform work.  It gets a message that states what kind of work and other data about what to work on, then it finds and loads the assembly necessary.  Each of these task assemblies references a shared assembly, and many of them share one or two other components.

Currently I have each task contained in its own solution.  There will eventually be about 50 tasks so developing in a ginormous solution like that would be a bit unwieldy. However, to keep tasks from getting out of date, I would like to create a mega solution that would let us check that changes to a shared component will/will not break a task.

## The Current Setup

### Task 1 Solution

- TaskBaseClasses
- Task1DataLayer
- Task1
- AnotherSharedProject

### Task 2 Solution

- TaskBaseClasses
- Task2DataLayer
- Task1DataLayer
- Task2
- AnotherSharedProject

If I make a change to a class in the TaskBaseClasses project, that change has to be checked against the other projects containing references to that changed class.  With two tasks, this is not a big deal.  When we have 40 or 50 tasks it will be a real pain to open every one of them and make the changes.

### Deployment

In deployment the application is setup like so:
ApplicationDirectory

1. ApplicationDirectory

   - Tasks

     - Task1

       - Task1.dll
       - TaskBaseClasses.dll
     - Task2

       - Task2.dll
       - TaskBaseClasses.dll
   - ProcessApplication.exe
   - Otherstuff.dll

The above illustrates another problem.  When I build out the tasks individually, all of the shared references are duplicated.  This is not a problem now, but when I have 50 copies of TaskBaseClasses.dll

## The Setup I Want

So I would really much rather have (in addition to my smaller individual task assembly solutions) a large solution that would allow me to check all of the tasks for consistency with respect to shared assemblies, AND build everything in such a way that there is as little binary duplication as possible by hosting shared assemblies in a separate place and projects can refer to them by relative path.

### MegaSolution

- TaskShared

  - TaskBaseClasses
  - Task1DataLayer
  - AnotherSharedProject
- Task1

  - Task1
- Task 2

  - Task2
  - Task2DataLayer

### Deployment

1. ApplicationDirectory

   - Tasks

     - Task1

       - Task1.dll
     - Task2

       - Task2.dll
     - TaskSharedComponents

       - TaskBaseClasses
       - Task1DataLayer
   - ProcessApplication.exe
   - Otherstuff.dll

Is this feasible?  I want to keep the Development solutions AND create a more or less Deployment solution.  When I start changing the references for the deployment solution, won't that throw off the references in the development solutions?

We are using TFS 2012 (soon to be upgraded to 2013) automated builds, and I would love nothing more than to have a nightly build of the mega solution ready for testing.

How can I have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds good to me. Use smaller solutions for more localized sets of tasks--perhaps as little as one task per solution--and mega solutions as necessary.

An alternative is to not use binary references for communication between tasks. Consider a more resilient-to-change coupling like HTTP services using JSON. It's much easier to maintain backward compatibility that way.

When you need to share *code*, use assembly references. When you need to share *behavior*, consider using HTTP services.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I will have to look into that.  How simple is it to implement?  We are expecting like 50 tasks, and each one is likely to have at least two of it's own shared components to add into the mix.  At the end, there very well may be close to 150+ assemblies.

Comment: In our case, the most oft shared assembly is the ProcessTaskCommon assembly which has the base class and an interface used for the common entry point into all of the tasks.  Most of the other shared assemblies are data layer specifications that may be used by 2 or more tasks to get data in and out of the database.  Now we ARE hosting these tasks in multiple instances of a self hosting WCF service that loads them as needed, but so far that is as far as we have gone with that.

Comment: I just think that, although HTTP services require more *initial* work, it pays off in the long run. You can scale tasks independently of one another, set them up on different servers, run them in the cloud, etc. more easily. With a tight binary coupling, it'll be nearly impossible to get those benefits. It all depends on where you see your architecture going in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

A hand-crafted solution could be a maintenance nightmare. I suggest to have strict naming and structure convention for your projects so you can easily script the collector and deploy.